# Open source(free) UML tools for Java to generate codes

Tags: java, uml, code-generation

I'm seeking UML tools(open source/free) for Java to generate codes of POJO(Java Bean)

What I need is quite simple. I write the UML diagram and the tools help to generate relevant .java files with the fields and get()/set() methods.

And it would be better if the tools are able to generate sql scripts(CRUD) as well base on the UML diagram

Thx

Comment: try Oracle JDeveloper IDE buddy :)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [GenMyModel](http://www.genmymodel.com), it's an UML-compliant online modeling tool with collaboration features, Java/Sql code generation. I really enjoy it; what it does from a web browser is absolutely awesome. (no setup, no install!).